# Adding @EnvironmentObject from a List row - No ObservableObject error

Tags: ios, swiftui, navigation, environment-variables

**This error is in more questions on SO, but I have not been able to solve my issue with the answers therein.**

I am trying to pass down an object down the view hierarchy using `@EnvironmentObject` but keep getting the following crash at the line with `crash 1` (see code at end of question):

> Thread 1: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type Entry found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for Entry may be missing as an ancestor of this view.

`Entry` is an `NSManagedObject`.

I don't understand what the "ancestor of this view" could be and where I should add `.environmentObject(entry)` to make this work. I also tried to add it directly after `EntryActionView()` and then the crash happens at the line with `crash 2`.

What am I missing?

Here's the code:

```
struct EntriesView: View {
    @FetchRequest(
        entity: Entry.entity()
    ) var entries: FetchedResults<Entry>

    @State private var searchText: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(entries.filter { $0.contains(searchText) }, id: \.self) { entry in
                    EntryRow(entry: entry)
                }
                .onDelete(perform: delete)
            }

            .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
            .searchable(text: $searchText)
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
    }
}


struct EntryRow: View {
    @StateObject var entry: Entry

    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: EntryActionView()) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 6) {
                // lots of info to display here, omitted for brevity
            }
        }.environmentObject(entry) // <<<--- this is where I add `entry` to the environment
    }
}


struct EntryActionView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var entry: Entry

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section {
                EntryInfoRow(title: entry.fullName) // <<<---- crash 1 here
            }

            Section {
                NavigationLink(destination: View1()) // <<<---- crash 2 in View1 when tapping on row
             
                // and more links, omitted for brevity
            }
        }
        .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
        .navigationTitle("Info")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this link, it gives you examples of how to manage data in your app:  
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app
 just copy and paste the examples to your code.

Comment: Thanks - I have seen that before and I think I am coding it as described there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble passing data between views using EnvironmentObject in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68347979/trouble-passing-data-between-views-using-environmentobject-in-swiftui)

Comment: Injecting in the `NavigationLink` does not mean it is available to all the Views below.

Comment: Oh, I see, it should be injected in a `NavigationView` instead. I’ll look into it later today.

Comment: @loremipsum Since `List` is already in the `NavigationView`, how do I inject the selected `entry` into the environment?

Comment: You can only do it to the destination, the scope is much more limited. You will have to reinject into the destination of the second link too.

Comment: Understood, I think I will go back to DI.